# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this code to retrieve data from a datagrid and then store then in another datatable. But I am getting the exception as: 
`"Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.`" This exception comes after `"dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)"`

Please do let me know if there are any faults, or any additional information is needed.

Code:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("IsActive", typeof(bool));
         dt.Columns.Add(c1);

         DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox_QCList1", typeof(string));
         c2.MaxLength = 500;
         dt.Columns.Add(c2);

         DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("DataGridTextBox_QCSummary", typeof(string));
         c3.MaxLength = 500;
         dt.Columns.Add(c3);

         DataColumn c4 = new DataColumn("DataGridComboxBox_Control", typeof(string));
         c4.MaxLength = 500;
         dt.Columns.Add(c4);  

     foreach (DataRowView d in dtgQCNumbers.Items)
     {
    DataRow dr = d.Row;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
     }
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
    qcId = row["QC_ID"].ToString();
    zipFolderPath = baseFolderPath;
    patternFiles = Directory.GetFiles(zipFolderPath, "*.zip");

    logMessage = "Unzipping file from path" + zipFolderPath + " \n file name:" + patternFiles[0];
    Common.LogMessage(logMessage);

    UnZipReleasePatch(zipFolderPath, patternFiles.First());
    //deploy release patch.
    logMessage = "Deploying files" + zipFolderPath;
    Common.LogMessage(logMessage);
    DeployFiles();
}
```

Comment: You need to define DataTable `schema`.

Comment: Try to add just new data row, not its items: dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Comment: I tried dt.Rows.Add(dr) initially, but to no avail. Then tried dt.ImportRow(dr) and dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray): still not able to isolate the reason for the exception

Comment: Hi AVD, had defined the structure of the Datatable

Comment: Try to create new row with dt.NewRow() and then populate its columns manually?

Comment: What code you've used to bind the DataGridView? If DataGridView's bind data source is DataTable then no need to creates/copy new DataTable.

Comment: Jleru, trying now and posting the result in a moment.

Comment: Hi AVD, yes the Datagrid is bound to a datatable. But how do I iterate the values of a particular column in the datagrid without storing the datagrid into a new datatable?

Comment: AVD, wokring straight on the earlier bhound datatable seems to work. Will keep you posted. :) Thanks

Comment: @Ashutosh - Sorry! I didn't get you. Now, I think you've used `DataSource` of "bounded - dataGridView". Isn't it?

Comment: Hi AVD, actually I bounded my DataGrid to a Datatable and used the same. :) thanks a lot for your tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AVD, got my answer as follows:

```
foreach (DataRow d in _ds.Tables[0].Rows)
         {
             if (d["DataGridComboxBox_Control"].ToString() == "AVS_DB")
             {
                 qcId = d["DataGridTextBox_QCList1"].ToString();
                 zipFolderPath = baseFolderPath;
                 patternFiles = Directory.GetFiles(zipFolderPath, "*.zip");

                 logMessage = "Unzipping file from path" + zipFolderPath + " \n file name:" + patternFiles[0];
                 Common.LogMessage(logMessage);

                 UnZipReleasePatch(zipFolderPath, patternFiles.First());
                 logMessage = "Deploying files" + zipFolderPath;
                 Common.LogMessage(logMessage);
                 DeployFiles();
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `DataGrid.Items` can contain a `NewItemPlaceholder` which is used to allow the user to add new items. You cannot indisciminately iterate over the collection for that reason, either filter out that item or iterate over the `ItemsSource` instead.

Comment: I'm getting the very same error for an `ItemsControl.Items` bound to an `ObservableCollection<Point>` (I have tried `List<Point>` too, no good). Why should `ItemsControl.Items` have `NewItemPlaceholder` in it?

Comment: @dotNET: It's the same property, maybe the functionality is already implemented in the `ItemsControl`, as it is rather generic.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to add new rows you can simply write in XAML :

CanUserAddRows="False"

and the placholder will be lost, so you can iterate until you will turn it on again.